# c# possible solutions to better type safety in dictionarys

Tags: c#, types

I have a number of objects with IDs of type int, for example a Product class with a productId and a Customer class with customerId. Sometimes I feel the IDs are easy to mix up, and Im thinking of solutions to make the type system enforce the distinction between them like you would do in for example Haskell.

This problem is most obvious when I have a multiple dictionaries that save the objects for quick access by ID:

```
Dictionary<int, Product> products;
Dictionary<int, Customer> customer;
Dictionary<int, List<Customer>> customersByProduct;

customerByProduct[what_id?].Add(new Customer())
```

Now when I have code that uses these dictionaries its possible to mix up whats used as dictionary key, especially if there's a more complicated setup with more dictionaries and the objects have multiple IDs.

Some thinking game me two solutions that can improve the situation, and I basically what input on if there are any other good ways to handle it, and if its a good idea at all?

So far I haven't experienced a real mixup, just a feeling that it started to be a little bit complicated. The code in question is being written right now, so if these types of bugs even happen I dont know, but I imagine that the major risk is later when other developers comes around and need to change/add something.

```
private struct CustomerId
{
    public CustomerId(int id)
    {this.id = id;}
    public override string ToString()
    {return id.ToString();}

    public int id;
}

private enum ProductId { }

void Main()
{
    var customers = new Dictionary<CustomerId, string>();
    var products = new Dictionary<ProductId, string>();

    customers[new CustomerId(1)] = "Customer1";
    customers[new CustomerId(2)] = "Customer2";
    customers[new CustomerId(3)] = "Customer3";

    products[(ProductId)1] = "Product1";
    products[(ProductId)2] = "Product2";
    products[(ProductId)3] = "Product3";

    customers.Dump();
    products.Dump();

    customers[new CustomerId(2)].Dump();
    products[(ProductId)3].Dump();

    int cid = customers.Keys.First().id;
    int pid = (int)products.Keys.First();
    cid.Dump();
    pid.Dump();
}
```

(example can be run directly in linqpad)

Comment: Have you actually had a problem with mixing up id values? If not, then you're wasting time solving a problem that will never occur.

Comment: No :) The context is that a big chunk of our core logic is rewritten from scratch, where the old solution did not have these constructs to start with. You could argue that more errors caught by the compiler is better, and if it is a good idea then its best to implement it from the start before the bugs actually appear. Anyway, part of why I wrote the question was to find out if its a good idea at all, maybe its not?

Comment: It's a good idea to solve actual problems before solving imaginary problems. OTOH, if this was ever a problem once, then I'd say it would be a good idea to solve it wherever it might occur. But only after the problem occurs once.

Answer (score 3):

`Dictionary` is a pretty low level class if your trying to do something advanced as you clearly are you could create classes like `CustomersRepository` which will hold raw Dictionary inside, and will expose better named methods like `GetCustomerById(int id)` or `int AddCustomer(Customer toAdd)` which will encaspulate access to `Dictionary`.

From your example its unclear at what moment you start to mixup ids, and where they are naturally coming from.

Both your approaches look too hacky to me.

Answer (score 3):

That is one way of doing this. You can make your identifier generic to prevent you from having to make a new implementation for each entity (or model or dto or what you have) like:

```
struct Identifier<TEntity>
{
    private int _id;

    public Identifier(int id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get { return _id; } }

    public static implicit operator int(Identifier<TEntity> identifier)
    {
        return identifier.Id;
    }

    public static implicit operator Identifier<TEntity>(int id)
    {
        return new Identifier<TEntity>(id);
    }

    // todo: implement compare logic
}
```

The implicit operators will allow you to easily use the identifier where ints are expected and the other way around, that is:

```
    static void UpdateFoo(int id, Foo foo)
    {
        // do something
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Identifier<Foo> identifier = 1;
        UpdateFoo(identifier, new Foo());
    }
```

Now a real question you might want to ask yourself is whether you really want an external identifier. Why not put the Id in your entity classes?

```
class EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }

    // tood: implement compare logic
}

class Foo : EntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can just make use of sets rather than a dictionary and you dont have to keep on passing 2 arguments around.

Comment: Interesting solution! Yes, a little bit more convenient to not have to create the same thing for each class.

The problem with HashSet is that you cant get the object back in more or less constant time if all you have is the ID.

Comment: So if we have 100 tables we will have 100 ways to present int? sounds not very good to me. All the casting isn't simplyfing things. And most importantly, whats the source of those Identities<T>? Usually its RDBMS where all 100 tables share single type of key most likely, which makes whole approach very questionable.

Comment: @viblo - Back in with only id? not sure i understand what you mean... HashSet has O(1) insertion time. Do you mean you can't remove easily when you only have the Id? That would be a good argument for prefering a Dictionary over a hashSet yes...

Comment: @ValentinKuzub - I dont totally agree with you. C# lacks #DEFINE like C/C++ enjoys. So this is a workaround for that. In C you massively use this and think about it. What if in C++ size_t was actually declared as an int in all API's. That would be a hell when switching to 64bit architectures since each API method should be updated. If the QA ever decides to use Long's as ID's rather than int's he now only has to change a few lines of codes. I'm not saying i want to propogate this approach but i assume it can be usefull in some circumstances

Comment: @ValentinKuzub - one question, why are you affraid of casting complicating things? By having an implicit cast operator both ways, casting by the user shouldnt even be required, ever.  That makes this just a way of annotating for what type of Entity this key is ment so you have both the information which collection and which entity within that collection, which can be very usefull...

Comment: its really hard to discuss this as I cannot relate to actual problem, its still unclear where the keys are coming from, and its very important when we choose any solution. As for casting - I am not afraid, I am cautious. In your case any int can be implicitly cast back and from any kind of Identity<TEntity>. This kind of gets us back to initial problem, but with much more complex code. Anyway just my thoughts about this. Id rather see source of keys :)

Comment: @Polity - I mean that if you have the ID and want the full object, a Dictionary has retrieval by key in O(1), and HashSet is much slower.